# How to correctly send RPC call using Golang to get smart-contract owner?

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, golang

**Update 12 November 2018**

Someone shared a very close solution to what I was looking for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53260846/1577357).

**Update 10 November 2018**

Since I'm not able to achieve this using the approach in this question, I created my own library to do the same thing ([link](https://github.com/zulhfreelancer/go-ethereum-get-contract-owner)). It doesn't rely on go-ethereum package but use the normal `net/http` package to do JSON RPC request.

I still love to know what I did wrong in my approach below.

---

**Definitions**:

- **owner** = `public` variable in contract with `address` type
- **contract** = smart-contract that has **owner**

This is the curl request to get the owner of a contract. I managed to get the owner.

```
curl localhost:8545 -X POST \
--header 'Content-type: application/json' \
--data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0", "method":"eth_call", "params":[{"to": "0x_MY_CONTRACT_ADDRESS", "data": "0x8da5cb5b"}, "latest"], "id":1}'

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"0x000000000000000000000000_OWNER"}
```

But when I try to replicate it in Golang (code below), I got *json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type main.response* error.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/rpc"
)

func main() {
    client, err := rpc.DialHTTP(os.Getenv("RPC_SERVER"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer client.Close()

    type request struct {
        To   string `json:"to"`
        Data string `json:"data"`
    }

    type response struct {
        Result string
    }

    req := request{"0x_MY_CONTRACT_ADDRESS", "0x8da5cb5b"}
    var resp response
    if err := client.Call(&resp, "eth_call", req, "latest"); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%v\n", resp)
}
```

What did I miss here?

Expected result:

Address in string format. E.g. `0x3ab17372b25154400738C04B04f755321bB5a94b`

P/S — I'm aware of abigen and I know it's better and easier to do this using abigen. But I'm trying to solve this specific issue without using abigen method.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
type response struct {
    Result string
}
```

just pass the result string

```
var result string
if err := client.Call(&result, "eth_call", req, "latest")
```

and parse the address

```
owner := common.HexToAddress(result)
fmt.Printf("%s\n", owner.Hex())
```

**Full code**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/rpc"
)

func main() {
    client, err := rpc.DialHTTP("https://mainnet.infura.io")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer client.Close()

    type request struct {
        To   string `json:"to"`
        Data string `json:"data"`
    }

    var result string

    req := request{"0xcc13fc627effd6e35d2d2706ea3c4d7396c610ea", "0x8da5cb5b"}
    if err := client.Call(&result, "eth_call", req, "latest"); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    owner := common.HexToAddress(result)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", owner.Hex()) // 0x281017b4E914b79371d62518b17693B36c7a221e
}
```